# Updation of states conditionally, setting and updating state with different set of states, in optimal way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

Updating react states based on some condition, in the most optimal way, where number of states are numerous and tough to handle.

Is there any way to add and omit states in react js based on some condition, like suppose I have an object like given below:

```
 const [bioStates, setBioStates] = useState({
    tissue: "",
    tissueContactingArr: [],
    bio_attach: [],
  });
```

Now I have three radio options and on the click of each button's click, I want to add or push different set of states in tissueContactingArr, say object of different states in each option, now the problem is, as I click the first option, a set of objects get set in tissueContactingArr, but now on other button click I want to update the set of objects by other set of objectx. THe major problem is I have to manage such 40-50 states, is there any optimal way to update such objects.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Natalya according to question you want to update state objects when they're triggered.
For this you can use id for input or div element for example-

```
<input
id="tissue"
value={bioStates?.tissue}
onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

while handleChange Function will be like-

```
const handleChange = (e)=>{
{value,id} = e.target
if(id==="tissue"){
let data = bioStates
data[id]=value
setBioStates((prev)=>({...prev},data))
}
}
```

you can try above code, if you still facing issue just let me know i will help you more.